# Update Parent table based on child records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi all I want to update parent table's Status depend on child records.

Condition is.

> Child records having the field `Isclosed`.

1. if all child records `Isclosed=1` then Parent records status=1
2. if some of the child records `Isclosed=1` then Parent records status=2
3. else Parent records status=3

Ihave tried this:

```
update Parent set Status=1
where id in(
select ParentID from Child where
Isclosed=1  
 group by ParentID having count(id)=(select count(id)from Child where Parent.id=ParentID))
```

But it satisfy only 1 condition.

Comment: Please post sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `CTE` to get the `COUNT`s of the `Child` records with `IsClosed = 1` and also the `COUNT` fo `Child` records per `Parent`. Then use the result of the `CTE` to `UPDATE` the status of the `Parent` records:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT
        p.Id,
        ClosedCount = SUM(CASE WHEN c.IsClosed = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        TotalCount = COUNT(*)
    FROM Parent p
    INNER JOIN Child c
        ON c.ParentId = p.Id
    GROUP BY p.Id
)
UPDATE p
    SET p.Status =
        CASE
            WHEN c.ClosedCount = c.TotalCount THEN 1
            WHEN c.ClosedCount = 0 THEN 3
            ELSE 2          
        END
FROM Parent p
INNER JOIN Cte c
    ON c.Id = p.Id
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/29599/2/0)

Comment: YES. I will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple query, may be help you

```
UPDATE  P
SET P.status = (CASE WHEN MaxIsclosed = MinIsclosed AND MaxIsclosed > 0 THEN 1
                    WHEN MaxIsclosed > 0 THEN 2 ELSE 3 END)
FROM    Parent P
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT PARENTID,MAX(Isclosed) AS MaxIsclosed,MIN(Isclosed) AS MinIsclosed 
    FROM CHILD  GROUP BY PARENTID)  C ON P.PARENTID = C.PARENTID
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go through the following query.

```
UPDATE [Parent]
 SET    [Status]  = CASE WHEN EXISTS (  SELECT  [ParentID]
                                        FROM    [Child]
                                        WHERE   [ParentID] = [Parent].[id]
                                        GROUP BY [ParentID]
                                        HAVING SUM([Isclosed]) = COUNT([ParentID])
                                    )
                        THEN    1
                        WHEN EXISTS (   SELECT  [ParentID]
                                        FROM    [Child]
                                        WHERE   [ParentID] = [Parent].[id]
                                        GROUP BY [ParentID]
                                        HAVING SUM([Isclosed]) = 0
                                    )
                        THEN    3
                        ELSE    2
                    END
```

You can CAST [Isclosed] to INT if needed.

Comment: What is the need for the WHERE condition here?